# Poetry packaging several dependencies

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-poetry

I have a project with several packages:

```
Project  
|---PackageA  
|------dist  
|----------packagea.whl  
|------pyproject.toml  
|---PackageB  
|------dist  
|----------packageb.whl  
|------pyproject.toml
```

PackageB has PackageA as a dependency.

Right now I have PackageB pyproject.toml like this:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]  
packagea = {path = "../PackageA", develop = true}
```

I then send both wheel files to another "prod" machine and try to install them.
I can't publish in PyPI the packages for IP reasons.

PackageA installation passes, however PackageB installation fails.
That happens because PackageB is looking for PackageA at the same location it was in my original "dev" machine.

1. I don't understand something basic:
   When I install PackageA, I see it installed as "packagea" in my python environment (using pip list).
   When I install PackageB, if packagea is already installed, shouldn't it skip this dependency installation?
2. What is the correct way to build packages and shipping them without PyPI?
3. Is there a way to pip install packageb.whl excluding ONLY "packagea" dependecy? Obviously, there will be no problem running the project, because python will find "packagea" in its environment.

UPD.:
Currently, I see no legit way to build 2 local packages for deployment without external repository (PyPI or Git). Pip's requirement to use absolute paths in dependencies leads to "PackageB" being not portable, because you can't know the deployment path of a local dependency in advance.
In simple words: There's no official way to build/publish a package with a local dependency (without workaround). It will be not installable.

Comment: Do `PackageA` and `PackageB` need to be in separate distributions, or would it work just as well for you to put both packages in the same distribution? Usually the only reason you'd need to have multiple distributions is if you intend to publish them separately to some (private) index, but from your description it sounds like you don't plan to do that.

Comment: Ignoring that path dependency for the moment, putting `packagea` in the dependencies of `packageb` means asking the integration frontend (e.g. pip) to search for and resolve that dependency at install time. If you don't want the integration frontend to do that, you may want to step back and consider whether separately packaged distributions make sense for your use case. If you do want these distributions to work with normal dependency resolution, then you can simply tell pip where it can find the wheel files (e.g. using `--find-links` or `--index-url`).

Comment: Using a local path dependency is problematic, since that path dependency is inserted into the wheel file as an _absolute path_, which is basically guaranteed not to exist on the "prod" machine. If you want to keep these packages in separate distributions and be able to create portable wheel files for them, you may want to consider connecting them in a different way on the "dev" machine.

Comment: PackageA and PackageB are separated for a reason of reusability. PackageA can be used independently or as a dependency of a bigger tool, like PackageB.

Comment: And if I add the packagea.whl as a dependency, will it still use the whl's absolute path in the packageb wheel file?

Comment: Seems to be a poetry design flaw, which leads to limited whl portability.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46651848/1100913 --find-links is probably the way to go. I can put all the wheel files in one directory and ask pip to consider it for dependency lookup. I will get back to you when I test this option. Thanks for now for the reference!

Comment: Yes, that would result in an absolute path too. Unfortunately, this is part of the wheel spec and isn't something that poetry has control over. I know since tried something very similar about a year ago. There's also a number of discussions about local path dependencies on poetry's issue tracker that may help you find a good solution (unfortunately I don't have any links handy).

Comment: One related issue I found: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/5273 (which links to https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9127)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64809439/1100913 So, no relative paths. That leaves me with only a workaround way.  The packageb.whl must include absolute path to packagea that's stored locally. But I can't know in advance where it will be deployed. Only a package consumer (some other person) will decide it afterwards. Git/pypi are not an option, like I mentioned before.

Comment: [Hosting your own private index](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/hosting-your-own-index/) is an option. That can be as simple a folder on your local machine. You could also move the path dependency to a dependency group which only gets installed on the "dev" machine, and then rely manually installation on the "prod" machine.